# How top expand collapse custom cell tableview and expanding the cell must be dynamic height in iOS objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

How top expand collapse custom cell tableview and expanding the cell must be dynamic height in iOS objective c?
viewcontroller having custom tableview cells when click on the cell,cell must be expand/collapse having one view and display data in that view and height must be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to maintain a state (expanded/not expanded) for the custom table view cell. Every time it's tapped you make the necessary changes in the UI and toggle the state. You can then call

```
reloadData()
```

or

```
-(void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths 
          withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation;
```

You can also calculate and set the new height of the cell and the reload function will take care of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You used tableview then easy manage expand and collapse custom cell tableview and expanding with animation.

Follow code for expand and collapse.

.h File

```
BOOL currentlyExpanded;
NSMutableIndexSet *expandedSections;
```

.m File

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  if (!expandedSections)
  {
      expandedSections = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
  }
}
```

Use Tableview Delegate and Datasource method..

```
#pragma mark - Tableview Delegate -

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canCollapseSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section])
    {
       if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section])
         return 6;  //return your array count..
       else
         return 1;
    }
     return 1;
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

      if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier]
            ;
      }
      if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])

       {
          //Display your dynamic cell contain.. 
       }
   return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])

     {
            NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
             currentlyExpanded = [expandedSections containsIndex:section];
             NSInteger rows;

              if (currentlyExpanded)
              {
                  rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
                [expandedSections removeIndex:section];

              }
              else
              {

                  [expandedSections addIndex:section];
                  rows = [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
              }

        // Animation when cell expand and collapse 

            if(currentlyExpanded)
            {
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                CGFloat startRadians, endRadians;
                startRadians = M_PI/2;
                endRadians = 0.0f;

                btnArrow.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(startRadians);

                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
                    btnArrow.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(endRadians);
                }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                }];


            }
            else
            {
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:tmpArray
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
                    [btnArrow setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(btnArrow.transform, M_PI/2 )];
                }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                }];

            }
     }
 }
```